# How to Process Braintree Payment with existing customerId

Tags: php, payment, braintree

Trying to set up iOS and PHP payment system using Braintree.

I can set up a clientToken with

```
$clientToken["client_token"] = Braintree_ClientToken::generate());
return ($clientToken);
```

And I can process a first payment with:

```
$result = Braintree_Transaction::sale(array(
        'amount' => '1',
        'paymentMethodNonce' => $nonce,
        'customer' => array(
            'id' => 'testId',
            'firstName' => 'John',
            'lastName' => 'Doe',
            'email' => 'john@doe.com',
        ),
        'options' => array(
            'submitForSettlement' => true,
            'storeInVaultOnSuccess' => true,
        )
      ));
```

However when I try to process a second payment I get the error:

```
91609 – Customer ID has already been taken.
```

How can I process a second payment for the same customer with the same customerId ('testId') - why does it throw an error when I try to pass the payment with an existing customer ID? Surely it should just attach the payment to that same customer? Isn't that what it's there for?

Edit:
So after looking around a bit more I found another field I can include in the Braintree_Transaction::sale as follows:

```
'customerId' => 'testId',
```

So this will allow me to re-use a customerId stored in the Braintree vault. However for a first time transaction I get the error:

```
91510 – Customer ID is invalid.
```

So I end up in a catch 22 - I can use the first set of code for a new customer but not repeat customers and I can use the second for repeat customers but not new. I cannot use both together. So my solution is to create my own local database entry that determines whether a user has paid via braintree before or not and substitute the code accorrdingly. Is there a more streamlined approach?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<sub>I work at Braintree. If you need more help, you can always [reach out to our support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

You've got the right idea. You need track on your side whether a customer ID exists with Braintree.

There is an alternative, but I don't recommend it, as it takes an extra API call.

You can first try to [create the customer with Braintree](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/ios+php/sdk/server/customer-management/create), ignoring an error if the error code is `91510`:

```
$result = Braintree_Customer::create(array(
        'id' => 'testId',
        'firstName' => 'John',
        'lastName' => 'Doe',
        'email' => 'john@doe.com',
));
```

Then, you know that either the customer already existed, or you just created it, and you can use your second method to [create a transaction](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/ios+php/sdk/server/transaction-processing/create).

Comment: thanks @agf - I'll reach out to support if I run into any issues. I've noticed that there are some holes in the documentation, if you're able to point out to the documentation team - particularly my first bit of code above, the documentation is missing the fact that you have to create an array with item 'client_token' rather than just return the object otherwise iOS wont accept it.

Comment: I feel documentation is little sparse too. It is not intuitive either. So far Stackoverflow support is good :)

Comment: I think it would be nice to get two levels of errors. A payment error and a creation error in Braintree_Transaction::sale. Then we could create customers, payment methods and more without sacrificing the sale in case there were a duplicate.

Comment: @MaciekSemik You can, by [setting the "store in vault" option to "true"](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/transaction/sale/ruby#options.store_in_vault).

Comment: @agf do you know if this procedure still stands? Is there any improvement on being about to "create or use existing" in one call?

Answer (score 0):

There is other alternative, instead of looking in your database, you can use find('a_customer_id') in order to see if Braintree has already the user id. And then chose your first approach or the second one.